# Bitcoin Unconfirmed Transaction Tiny Fee

Tags: transactions, blockchain, electrum

I sent a huge amount of Bitcoin(.7) with a tiny fee. What can I do to get the transaction confirmed. Does it have to go through eventually? I can wait a week or two.

Otherwise I am looking for other ways to get it confirmed. Bitcoin was sent from Blockchain Info to Electrum. Electrum has a low fee warning sign next to the unconfirmed transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok question was posted in error. The fee was actually around $50 for $7500 which is ok and got 4 confirmations in 30 minutes. But I am  sure the initial fee was tiny (like 50 cents) and then changed to unknown, turning out to be the higher figure.